# Why is the LED of my Illuminated rocker switch always on?

Tags: led, power, switches

I recently purchased a rocker power switch from RadioShack ([103-R13-135B-02R-EV](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/103-R13-135B-02R-EV/?qs=FlsQBa5xHTY3xCWHkj1UHA==)) and  it works great.  However, even when the switch is off, the small red LED stays on.  Is this normal? Won't this unnecessarily drain my 9V battery?

Comment: There may be some confusion here.  The product page on Mouser says that illumination is LED.  The catalog page says `103-R13-135B-02R-EV [...] Illum. Green/Neon`.  The datasheet which you've linked, however, doesn't show the LED (drawing at the bottom-right of the first page).  It shows Neon.  However, you are saying that the illuminator had lit up from 9V supply.  A Neon lamp would not light up at such low voltage.  Is it possible that you have the part number (model number) confused?

Comment: In any case, there's another question: how is your switch wired?  A diagram wouldn't hurt here.

Comment: I can't post a circuit at the moment, but how exactly do I wire this switch? I could not figure it out from the data sheet, so I simply rearranged my wiring until the switch worked.  Regarding the datasheet issue, it is possible I linked the wrong datasheet.  My switch has the lettering "R13-135" on it, and a google search returned the link I posted above.

Comment: http://www.sci.com.tw/PRODUCTS/switch/(R13)%20ROCKER%20SWITCH/R13-135.htm This link shows both led and neon, and to be honest, I'm not sure which one I have, as I've thrown out the packaging.

Comment: Is [this the switch you bought](https://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3118987)?

Comment: @BenMiller Yes it is.

Comment: @user43578  "...to be honest, I'm not sure which one I have, as I've thrown out the packaging."  *facepalm*...  Back in my days (and I'm not very old) they would send you to dive for it.  After pulling the packaging from the jaws of the garbage truck a few times, one learns the value of writing down part numbers, and of having a long-term garbage bin for dry technical packaging.

Comment: @user43578  How many contacts does your switch have?  From the photo on the RadioShack's web site, it looks like the switch has only 2 contacts on the back.  (It would not have killed RadioShack to post the photo of the rear, by the way.)

Comment: Based on the shadow in that picture, it looks like it has 3 contacts. I know I am connecting my power source to the middle contact.  Is that correct?

Comment: One of the reviews has this comment: 
"Pin #1 & Pin #2 - LED never on
Pin #2 & Pin #3 - LED always on
Pin #1 & Pin #3 - LED On & Off" -

I will try that when I get home.

Comment: The reviewer notes on the page @BenMiller linked to make it pretty clear how to wire it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is the internal schematic of your switch:

[image: switch schematic]

Based on that, if you want to wire the switch so that the light turns on and off with the switch, you would wire it as follows:

- Pin 1: +Voltage power in
- Pin 2: Switched power for your circuit
- Pin 3: 0 volts

I'm guessing that you have pin 1 and 2 reversed, which would cause the LED to be always on.

And to answer your question, yes, if the LED is on, you are draining your battery.  :)

Comment: I will wire this up when I get home, and post back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Except this is a Neon light and not an LED on the schematic.  The O.P. seems to be providing a datasheet after datasheet, which show something similar, but there is no evidence that they actually represent the physical part that he has got.  On that note, I stop following this wild goose chase of a question.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes, the schematic I grabbed has the wrong symbol for the light.  However, I believe that RadioShack only sells the LED version of this switch, so I still think my answer is correct.